# i want to open CS5 to CS3 version file in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have Adobe Indesign CS5 file.
I want to open this file in CS3 Version of Adobe Indesign please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do so would be to use CS4 as a bridge in between.

InDesign is only backward compatible for one version. So, you would have to export your CS5 file as IDML, open that in CS4, export it there as an INX file, and then open that in CS3.

This is well-documented; [this forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/641138?start=0&tstart=0) provides some discussion about the matter.

Answer (score 1):

InDesign CS5 and CS4 are only compatible one version back. But CS6 is three versions compatible. It saves IDML files that can be opened in CS5.5, CS5 and CS4.

IDML will be the interchange language going forward, so it should be easier to exchange files to users of older versions. BUT, remember, newer features will be absent or removed from the document when the IDML is opened in the older software.